# How to destroy Scotch Panels instance at certain breakpoint?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, removeclass

I'm using the [Scotch Panels](https://panels.scotch.io/) plugin for an off-canvas mobile navigation with a traditional dropdown taking over at 1023px (via CSS media queries and a debounced window.resize function that removes Panels' added classes and inline styles)

My problem is that Panels doesn't include a destroy() method and I cannot figure out how to reliably kill/reinitiate the plugin when dragging between the breakpoints. My following code seems to work, but only half of the time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($(window).width() < 1023){
        //Initiate Panels if initial window is > 1023...
        var scotchPanel = $('#primary-navigation').scotchPanel({
            containerSelector: 'body',
            direction: 'left',
            duration: 300,
            transition: 'ease',
            clickSelector: '.nav-toggle a',
            distanceX: '60%'
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() >= 1023) {
            //Remove everything (I can find) that Panels adds...
            $('body').removeClass('scotchified');
            $('#primary-navigation').removeClass("scotch-panel-left").removeAttr('style');
            $('.scotch-panel-canvas').removeAttr('style').attr('class', 'remove');
            $('.scotch-panel-wrapper').removeAttr('style').attr('class', 'remove');
            $('.remove').contents().unwrap();
        }
        if($(window).width() <= 1023) { 
        //Don't know how to check if the Panels is already initiated, 
          but that would probably be a good idea here...
            var scotchPanel = $('#primary-navigation').scotchPanel({
                containerSelector: 'body',
                direction: 'left',
                duration: 300,
                transition: 'ease',
                clickSelector: '.nav-toggle a',
                distanceX: '60%'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is a little deeper into JS/JQ plugin manipulation than I usually delve - am I missing something simple here?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I also implemented re-initializing a panel in a window.resize -- my `clickSelector` didn't work after the resize, once I did `$('#clickSelector').off() before reiniting the panel - it was ok. Other than that - I think that if you reinit the panel to the same variable - there shouldn't be a problem, memory-wise -- it's supposed to be overwritten.